# How to remove child commit from existing pr

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

It's silly really, I made a pull request yesterday on branch_A to master. Many files were changed and I don't want to add more to it. I switched to a new branch from branch_A to branch_B. I added the files I wanted to commit, and pushed from branch_B.

On Github, if I want to merge this commit to master, it shows that both the pr I made on a separate branch and this new commit are together. I did not want to push this commit to my previous pull request. I thought since I was on a new branch, that it would create a way to make a new pull request.

Should I remove the commit and try a different way? Should I merge the commit and pr? Should I just submit the pull request as is? Should I try to push this commit to Branch_A instead of master? There are many questions.

Here's a look at the cli steps:

- git branch -vv (master, *branch_A*)
- git checkout -b branch_B
- git add .
- git commit -m"something cool"
- git push origin branch_B

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

> switched to a new branch from branch_A to branch_B

Creating `branch_B` whilst having `branch_A` checked out resulted in `branch_B` being based off of `branch_A`:

### Tree 1

```
branch_B  // <- subsequent commits to branch_B
|
branch_A  // <- commits to branch_A
|
|
master
```

> I did not want to push this commit to my previous pull request.

If I've understood you correctly you'd rather have done this:

### Tree 2

```
branch_B  // <- commits to branch_B
|
|   branch_A  // <- commits to branch_A
| /
|
master
```

Here the commits to `branch_B` are applied to `master` and do not include the changes to `branch_A`.

To go from *Tree 1* to *Tree 2* you will need to do a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)*:

```
$ git checkout branch_B
$ git rebase master
$ git push -f # WARNING: this command will re-write the git history for this branch.
              # If other's use this git repo, especially if they have checked out `branch_B` locally, they should be consulted first.
```

---

**With the rebase command, you can take all the changes that were committed on one branch and replay them on a different branch.*